# Design of a dynamique table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table, every line of this table contains a group of (input,select...).
For the first time i display just the first line of the table and when i click on the button "icon plus" i display(make style.display=inline) the second line...etc 
My problem is that: when i click on button "icon plus" the second line is displayed but the width of the first "select" of the first line is modified! (it becomes bigger) 
Before clicking on "icon plus":[image]
After: 
[image]

html code:

```html
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="horizontal-form">
       
                                   @using (Html.BeginForm("RechercheForm", "Recherche", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SearchForm", @class = "" }))
                                   {
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search icon-ser"></i></button>
                 </span>
                                            
                                             
                                            
                                                
                                            <table id="TableRech" class="table" >
                                              <tr>
                                
                                  
                                              </tr>
                                                @for (var i = 0; i < names.Count(); i++)
                                                {
                                                    
                                    
                                                    <tr id="TrToHide@(i + 1)">
                                                <td>

                                              <select   class="form-control1" id="Critere@(i + 1)" name="List[@(i)].Critere"  onchange="CleanCritere(@(i + 1),this);CallChangefunc(this.value,@(i + 1))"> <!-- some attrs=ibutes skipped --><option selected disabled value="">Aucun</option></select>
         
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                            
                                               <select class="form-control1" id="Op@(i + 1)" name="List[@(i)].Op"   onchange="OnclickBetween(@(i + 1),this.value)"  > <!-- some attrs=ibutes skipped --><option selected disabled value="">Aucun</option></select>
         
                                                </td>
                             
                                                <td>
      
                                               <input class="form-control1" type="text" id="Val1@(i + 1)" name="List[@(i)].Val1" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="TdToHide@(i + 1)">
                                                    <input class="form-control1" type="text" id="Val2@(i + 1)" name="List[@(i)].Val2" />
      
                              
                                
                                                </td>
                                  
                                                  <td><span id="HidePlus@(i + 1)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"  style="width: 15px;" onclick="RechFunctionPlus()" ></span>
                                                  @if ((@i + 1) != 1)
                                                  {
                                                     <span id="HideMoins@(i + 1)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"  style="width: 15px;" onclick="RechFunctionMoins()" ></span>
                                   
                                                  }   
                                                      
                                                  </td>
                             
                                
                                
                                              </tr>
                                                    
                                                
                                                }
                              
                               
                                            </table>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="Counter" value="1" id="Counter" />
                            
                            
                            
                                   }
                            </div>
        
         </div>
```

Script:

```js
 function RechFunctionPlus() {
         
         var Counter = document.getElementById("Counter");

         //Hide the + and - of the current line
         var IdPlus = document.getElementById("HidePlus" + Counter.value);
         IdPlus.style.display = "none";
         if (Counter.value != 1) {
             var IdMoins = document.getElementById("HideMoins" + Counter.value);
             IdMoins.style.display = "none";

         }
         //incrementer de 1
         $('#Counter').val(function (i, oldval) {
             return ++oldval;

         });

         var Tr = document.getElementById('TrToHide' + Counter.value)
         Tr.style.display = "inline";
         if (Counter.value == FormLineMax) {
              IdPlus = document.getElementById("HidePlus" + Counter.value);
             IdPlus.style.display = "none";
         }
        
         
         
         //Make required=true for all elements of the added line

         var Critere = document.getElementById('Critere' + Counter.value);
         var Op = document.getElementById('Op' + Counter.value);
         var Val1 = document.getElementById('Val1' + Counter.value);
         Critere.setAttribute('required', 'required');
         Op.setAttribute('required', 'required');
         Val1.setAttribute('required', 'required');








     }
```

Comment: Change `...style.display = 'none'` to `...style.visibility = 'hidden'`

Comment: i have tried it but without result :(

Comment: Inspect your generated HTML to see where is your lost column